# Access "Server" field for a file on a SMB mounted NAS on mac via shell script or Applescript

Tags: swift, macos, applescript, automator, smb

In osx, the Information Window for a file loaded from a NAS via SMB contains a field called "server", with a full path to the string, e.g. "SMB://server.com/path/to/file.txt"

Unfortunately, the **server** property from system events seems no longer to work.  Apple, you're breaking my heart these days.

Does anyone have other ideas?  Perhaps Shellscripts?

Thank You!
Steve

[Old Example that no longer works](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2290642?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

This property can be read from shell instruction mdls. This instruction assumes that your volume has Spotlight index (it should be the case for almost all of your Mac volumes ...!).

mdls instruction runs on Terminal, or via a Applescript in a do shell script command. Your file path/name must be provided with Unix format (posix)

The syntax could be : "mdls /path/to/your/file " -> it gives you all attributes of the file (many).

You can also define which attribute you want to display. In your case the attribute is kMDItemWhereFroms, so syntax is : mdls -name kMDItemWhereFroms path/to/your/file

The result will be in the form : kMDItemWhereFroms = ("http:// xxxxxx")

The script below gives an example to select a file and display the serveur (if any). It parses the result to take only text between quote (car 34)

```
set theFile to ((choose file) as string)
set Source to do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemWhereFroms " & quoted form of (POSIX path of theFile)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {ASCII character 34} -- the char "
if (count of text item of Source) > 2 then
set myServer to text item 2 of Source
else
set myServer to ""
end if
display dialog myServer
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I'm only getting blanks, so perhaps the SMB volume is not indexed.  Is there another way to tell if it is indexed?

Comment: After checking on Google, it seems that SMB volume can be indexed via mdutil, but the system will build index for mdls command, only with file on the volume at indexation time...not very convenient ! It seems that spotlight index can run in background with shared volume only with mac OS server version (it makes sense since index should only contained linked to file users has authorization on !).. Sorry except mdls, I never found other clean solution. of course you can still script to open information windows, read the value and  close the windows...